# YII2: Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД без построителя

Tags: sql, yii2

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос к БД, построенный без построителя:

```
        $connection = (new \yii\db\Query());
        $connection->createCommand("select zx.period,(select count(id) from posting_addresses where period=zx.period) from (select period  from  posting_addresses group by period) as zx")->queryAll();
```

Однако выходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем я не прав?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Yii;
$posts = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select zx.period,(select count(id) from posting_addresses where period=zx.period) from (select period from  posting_addresses group by period) as zx")->queryAll()
```